# QPainter: как добавить текст без артефактов в шрифте

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Qt5, C++. Программно рисую картинку, на которую необходимо добавить текстовое содержимое. Какой бы шрифт не использовал - на выходе получаю артефактные гличи: буквы испещрены точками, неточностями, "шумом".

Краткий пример моего кода и скриншот:

```
    m_font.setFamily(family);
    m_font.setPointSize(FONT_SIZE);
    m_font.setBold(true);


    QPainterPath path;
    QFontMetrics fm(m_font);
    path.addText(0, fm.height(), m_font, "LOREM IPSUM");

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&img);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::black);
    painter.drawPath(path);
    painter.end();
```

[image: Скриншот]

Пробовал играться с масштабом - большого толку нет: увеличил изображение и шрифт в 10 раз, а при выводе картинки использовал `QImage::scaled(X, Y)`. Скриншот:

[image: Попытка с масштабированием]

Как получить "гладкое" начертание букв на итоговой картинке?

Comment: А что будет если рисовать не через path, а напрямую - `painter.drawText`? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawText

Comment: m_font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::NoAntialias);?

Comment: @magrif, не помогло. Пробовал до написания вопроса сюда, но не упомянул. Рисовать текст напрямую через QPainter тоже не дало эффекта. Однако, спасибо за подсказку. Настройки алиасинга в QPainter дали результат!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не надо использовать для такой задачи `QPainterPath`

Вот такой сниппет я использовал для тестирования

```
QFont font;
font.setPointSize(52);
font.setBold(true);

QString example = "LOREM IPSUM 1234567890$%^";

QPainterPath path;
QFontMetrics fm(font);
path.addText(0, fm.height(), font, example);

QImage img(900, 200, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
img.fill(Qt::white);

QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&img);
painter.setBrush(Qt::black);
painter.drawPath(path);

painter.setFont(font);
painter.drawText(QPointF(0, fm.height() * 2), example);

painter.end();
```

И вот результат. Верхняя надпись как у вас, нижняя `drawText`

[image: результат]

Comment: Спасибо. Смог воспроизвести. Буду разбираться почему по вашему первому комменатрию не получилось. Видимо, слишком много параметров накрутил, да и выбранный шрифт перепроверю. Помогли :)

Answer (score 1):

Задал Render hint объекту QPainter:

```
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стало значительно лучше.